# Неопределённое поведение в python

Tags: python, неопределённое-поведение

Возможно ли в python получить неопределённое поведение? И если возможно, то как?

Comment: Что такое неопределённое поведение. Поясните термин

Comment: @hedgehogues это когда спецификация языка не определяет поведения языка в данной ситуации. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @nick_gabpe, насколько я знаю - это фишка C/C++. По крайней мере про неопределенное поведение в Python я никогда не слышал.

Comment: Можно посмотреть [какое поведение явно задокументировано как неопределённое в Питоне](https://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Необходим модуль bytecode(для генерации байткода).

```
import types

import bytecode
from bytecode import ConcreteInstr


code = bytecode.Bytecode()
code.append(ConcreteInstr('POP_TOP'))
stop_signal = types.FunctionType(code.to_code(), {})

stop_signal() #в доках питона не сказано что здесь произойдет сегфолт.(хотя это известно)
```

Answer (score -2):

Python выдаёт 10, в нем нет инкремента в таком виде:

```
 i = 5
 i = ++i + ++i
 print i

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def inc(self):
        self.num += 1
        return self.num

i = Foo(5)
print(i.inc() + i.inc())
```

потому, что интерпретатор вычисляет все по порядку.
Но если чуток подумать и довести все до логического ума, то все таки 14

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def inc(self):
        self.num += 1
        return self

    def __add__(self, right):
        return Foo(self.num + right.num)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.num)

i = Foo(5)
print(i.inc() + i.inc())
```

Comment: В чем неопределенное поведение?

Comment: @insolor по коду ++i это вообще то преинкремент, и должно быть 6, 6 + 6 = 12, выдает 10.... Поведение не определено.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, в Python вообще нет такого инкремента (ни пре- ни пост-). Нет инкремента - нет НП с ним связанного.

Comment: @insolor ну да, человек перепутал C с python :) Этакий троллинг.

Comment: ну немного есть) Но ответ по теме же. неопределенно!

Comment: @PhilipPilipchuk на самом деле есть возможность создать объект, который будет вести себя как в C... Есть методы ____pos____ и ____repr____, изменив которые операторы + и - будут давать весьма интересные эффекты.

Comment: да я в курсе, хотя никогда я их и не использовал. А вы в реальной жизни ими пользовались?

Comment: @PhilipPilipchuk, в данном случае неопределенности никакой нет: как реализуете, так и будет работать. Выдает, кстати 13 ((5+1) + (5+1+1)).